# "com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function" in production but in debug working fine

Tags: android, react-native

"com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: TypeError: undefined is not a function" coming  from playstore crash  log whereas in debug everything is working fine.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you